# Change texture in Unity 3D (C#)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 3 materials, each with unique textures, how can I change between the 3 dynamically in-game?

Answer (score 0):

If you are switching between materials you just do something like this depending on if you have a MeshRenderer (non rigged/animated) object or a SkinnedMeshRenderer (rigged/animated) object. If you select your GameObject in this inspector if you check you can see if your object has a MeshRenderer or SkinnedMeshRenderer. Assuming the MeshRenderer is on the same level as the script you are attaching.

```
Material redMaterial;
Material greenMaterial;

public void ChangeRedMaterial() {
    gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = redMaterial;
    //alternative gameObject.GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>().material = redMaterial;
}
```

depending ony our hierarchy you may need to use GetComponentInChildren instead of GetComponent. You can also pass other game objects and switch materials:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = gameObjectTwo.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material;
```